# Bin Creation from scala tuple array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array of tuple of form

```
Input: Array[(Long,Double)]
arr = Array[(1,3),(2,5),(3,9),(4,10),(5,3)]
```

Now I want to do some binning on the data. Here is the algorithm I am following:

1. I sort the array on second argument
2. Assign the first element as being in bin 0
3. If next element is same as previous then it goes in same bin otherwise I keep growing a bin till a specified size, say 10% of whole data
4. When a bin size grows more than the specified size a new bin is created.

   ```
   If bin size is assumed to be 1
   Output: Array[(1,0),(5,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)]
   ```

Currently I am able to do this via a simple iteration through the list comparing each value to previous and keeping track of bin sizes. Is there any efficient way to achieve this especially in scala?

Answer (score 1):

Well.. lets say you know the bin size ( you can get number of bins ) or the number of bins.

```
val numBins = 3

val arr = Array[(1,3),(2,5),(3,9),(4,10),(5,3)]

// sc is the SparkContext
val arrRdd = sc.parallelize( arr )

val sortedRdd = arrRdd.sortBy( ( t: ( Int, Int) ) => t._2 )

val binnedRdd = sortedRdd.repartition( numBins ).glom
```

Now, `binnedRdd` will be `RDD[ Array[ (Int, Int) ] ]` where each array will be your bin.

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh. But I don't have the number of bins beforehand. That depends on the data, based on the data that number can go up or down.

Comment: Well... You must have some method to determine bin size based on data size. Spark can not do that for you.